# permissions error when trying to install tensorflow in r

Tags: python, r, tensorflow

I get a permissions error when trying to install tensorflow for R.

Error: Error 2 occurred installing tensorflow package
In addition: Warning message: 
running command '"C:\Users\PAT~1.BAUST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36/Scripts/pip.exe" install --upgrade --ignore-installed "tensorflow" "h5py" "pyyaml" "requests" "Pillow"' had status 2

I am not sure what is going on. I am an administrator on the machine.

Everything else with the install goes fine. does anyone have any insight on this?

thanks much. 
PB